# How can I step into a SQL Server stored proc from my C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, debugging

I am debugging some C# code that uses Ado.net to call a stored proc (TSQL) in SQL Server.   How can I step into the stored proc?

(I think I have seen this demoed by Microsoft staff, but can’t recall the 101 “magic” settings that are needed to get it to work.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*I'll build on Davide's answer and Ian's comment to it because that was the exactly the process I have gone through.*

**Assumption**: answer is based on **VS2008 & VS2010**.

To step through a T-SQL stored procedure on SQL Server while debugging a .NET app you need to do the following:

1. Follow the MS Support instructions "**[How to debug stored procedures in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549) (Option 2)**"

   - Ensure that you have enabled **SQL Server debugging** in the project's properties (Step 4 in the linked instructions).
   - Ensure you have set a **breakpoint in the stored procedure** itself (Steps 6-7)
2. Enable the **Allow SQL/CLR Debugging** on the Data Connection on which the stored procedure is called:

   - (without this second step you'll be getting *"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unable to bind SQL breakponit at this time. Object containing the breakpoint not loaded."* as reported by Ian)
   - **Server Explorer** > Data Connections
   - **Right-click** on the connection that you are using in the code
   - Tick the **Allow SQL/CLR Debugging** option in the menu

---

Added from comments:  (This seem to be key to getting it to work)

It works with a programmatically created connection, too. You just have to use the **exact same connection string** that is displayed when you right-click the server instance, click on 'Properties' and scroll down to 'Connection string' (Verbindungszeichenfolge in German).

Comment: @Ian I am afraid you have to use a connection which is listed in the Server Explorer. None of the relevant documentation nor poking around in VS itself show that it'd be possible to do so for a programmatically created connection. So at least for debug/test purposes you'd need a listed connection.

Comment: I think "connection which is listed in the Server Explorer" is the to way this just works for some people but other people can never get it to work.

Comment: @Ian you are probably right. I wonder if that's concious design decision or an oversight...

Comment: NOTE: In VS 2013, step 4 of the  "How to debug stored procedures in Visual Studio .NET (Option 2)" link is: under the Web section of the tree.  Click Web and scroll down to the Debuggers section and you will see SQL Server there.

Comment: @IanRingrose it works with a programmatically created connection, too. You just have to use the exact same connection string that is displayed when you right-click the server instance, click on 'Properties' and scroll down to 'Connection string' (Verbindungszeichenfolge in German). Note that, apparently, you can add an Initial Catalog at the end of that string.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler,  That may explain it, the app I was trying to debug adds random bits to the connection string when it gets a database error, due to a bug in the ado.net connection caching retuning broken connections when server gone over to another one in the cluster.

Comment: @IanRingrose I tried using same connection string but still VS states that "the break point will not currently be hit". I have turned on "Application Debugging" and "SQL/CLR Debuggin" in SQL Server Object Explorer. I have also turned on SQL Server Debugging in my C# project. I am able to debug the stored procedure by executing it directly from "SQL Server Object Explorer" but I am unable to step through from C# code. Can someone help? I am using VS 2017.

Answer (score 8):

For those of you who are using VS 2012 and are confused as to why you cannot enable SQL/CLR Debugging from the Server Explorer window, you actually need to connect via the "SQL Server Object Explorer" window.

Once you have the connection in that window, the `Allow SQL/CLR Debugging` and `Application Debugging` setting appear on the right-click context menu of your server.  This probably applies to 2013 as well but I cannot confirm.

Comment: I found those settings in `SQL Server Object Explorer` in VS 2013, but still get message that breakpoint will not currently be hit.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem for me in VS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the SQL Server debugging in the project properties.

Comment: Sorry I have tied this, and Visual Studio just steps over the call to ExecuteReader(), rathern than stepping into the stored proc

Comment: I think you need debug permission to debug into the stored procedure, does the SQL server run on your local computer?

Comment: @J.W If a selected a stored proc from the server explorer I can step into it.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project (not the solution) and open the Property pages. Click Configuration Properties in the tree and then click to select the SQL Server Debugging check box on the Debugging page to enable stored procedure debugging.

reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549

Comment: When I got to set the break point in the stored proc I get "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.   Unable to bind SQL breakponit at this time.  Object containing the breakpoint not loaded."