# Using Visual Studio 2015 CE to Debug stored procedures called from .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am unable to debug a stored procedure called from .NET code using Visual Studio 2015 community edition.  After much trial an error I've managed to find a sample project that works (But with Visual Studio 2013).

Here is a [link to this project.](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1079275/debug-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-and-ssms)

I've written [more details about this problem here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c26c8c6-6d35-4c46-ae67-a2e7b3cdce28/using-visual-studio-2015-ce-to-debug-stored-procedures-called-from-net-code?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

I am trying to understand if Visual Studio 2015 community edition is able to debug stored procedures called from .NET code.  (I can debug stored procedures from the SQL Object Explorer directly) and if so what I can do to get this to work.

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885855/how-to-debug-stored-procedure-in-vs-2015) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737175/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-error-when-trying-to-debug-a-tsql).

Comment: Looks like an interesting question, but a lot of people are not going to go offsite to read it. If those links die we're left with a silly question here. Thumbs up for having at least done your homework and finding similar questions!

Comment: This shows how to do this using the community edition :[debugging with community edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885855/how-to-debug-stored-procedure-in-vs-2015)

Comment: @bilor sorry for the confusion but this is one the questions noted to not having a working answer. (sorry for the external link but it was a long post).. not sure if i should reask question including full text in external link to avoid downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

According to this it's probably not possible:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc36cda2-c947-4902-b339-c3f5de02b222/is-it-possible-to-debug-stored-procedures-using-visual-studio-community-2015?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

After further discussion a bug has been opened regarding this issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3117615

It seems to be related to Visual Studio 2015 CE Update 3.  I have not been able to confirm but if you have only the Original Visual Studio 2015 CE installed without any updates that it should work.

Here is a link to the discussion:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c26c8c6-6d35-4c46-ae67-a2e7b3cdce28/using-visual-studio-2015-ce-to-debug-stored-procedures-called-from-net-code?forum=vsdebug#f839fdd0-0316-44f3-82ab-adf2b0ebcb78