# Can Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition perform SQL debugging from unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2015, localdb

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (final release version) under Windows 8.1 64-bit.
- I'm using SQL Server Data Tools to develop some T-SQL stored procedures and deploy them into SQL Server 2014 LocalDB.
- I also have a project with C# unit tests, calling these stored procedures through ADO.NET. The "Enable SQL Server debugging" is turned-on under project's Properties / Debug.

In earlier versions of VS, I could put a breakpoint in T-SQL code, start debugging the C# unit test and it would hit the T-SQL breakpoint when it gets called via ADO.NET.

VS2015 Community doesn't do that - no error, it just silently ignores T-SQL breakpoint and continues stepping through C# code.

Does anybody know: is this a specific limitation of the Community edition, but is available in "higher" editions? Or is it an oversight that may get fixed in the future? Any references to documentation or developer blogs (or similar) would be greatly appreciated - I seem to be unable to find any...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have it working in Visual Studio 2015 Community (though I'm calling SQL via a web project, not a unit test project).

The answers here may be helpful: [How can I step into a SQL Server stored proc from my C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736216/how-can-i-step-into-a-sql-server-stored-proc-from-my-c-sharp-code)