# Step into stored procedure SQL Azure from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2017, localdb

Visual Studio 2017 community edition steps over my `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteNonQuery` with this code:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataContext"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var sc = new SqlCommand("InsertOrUpdate", con);
    sc.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", "some string code");
    var o = sc.ExecuteScalar(); // is null. cannot step into
    int newPrimaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(o); // stays zero
}
```

I have had an azure sql server in my app.config datacontext and also a localdb `Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true`
both do not step into the (same) stored procedure.
I have the same connectionstring in both my Visual Studio Server Explorer and the Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer.

When I open the file through either the server explorer or sql server object explorer and set a breakpoint and start debugging it always says that the breakpoint won't get hit.

I also have added the database as project to my solution explorer and checked the **enable sql debugging** in my projects properties.

[image]

I have read this [How can I step into a SQL Server stored proc from my C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736216/how-can-i-step-into-a-sql-server-stored-proc-from-my-c-sharp-code) similar question.

I can post the stored proc code if you want, but it's not so relevant as I cannot step into it to debug it.

this is my azure db version

> Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jun  7 2017 01:09:35   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

and this is my localdb

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 15063: ) (Hypervisor)

Running Visual Studio 2017 community 15.2 (latest stable)
and cloud explorer 1.1.1704.221
and ssms 17.1 (14.0.17119.0)

I also launched vs as administrator. also did not help.

The step4 of app debugging is not shown on my machine. Not in server explorer or sql server object explorer. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079275/Debug-Stored-Procedures-in-Visual-Studio-and-SSMS

[image]

seems checked at the localdb. not available as option for azure sql.

also when I manually want to run the stored proc from ssms, there is no debug option for the azure db.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Current as of November 2018, debugging is not supported on Azure SQL
[image]