# Debug a stored procedure being called from C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I need to debug a stored procedure that is being called from a C# application. I'm a database developer and I do not have access to the C# code. I only have access to the database where the stored procedure is present.

When the application developer runs his code to execute the stored procedure, I need to debug it.

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Why not use Sql Profile and capture everything that is executed including parameter values being passed / used. Then you can replay if you want or debug in SSMS.

Comment: i don't see the necessity, you tell him what data you expect and if he finds same data that doesn't work, he can send you them

Comment: It sounds like your testing methodology is flawed. The C# dev can use unit testing with mocks to ensure that the application is sending the correct parameter values and you can test your S/P by running it manually with various input data. Once both of these test suites have passed, then do your integration testing where the C# code actually calls the database.

Comment: Echo Dave; I see no reason why you cannot debug trhis SP using SSMS, completely independent of any c#

Comment: Echoing everyone else, if this is indeed MSSQL, *Make SQL Profiler your best friend*.

Comment: @sqldeveloper, based on my search, as others suggested, It is a good choice for you to use SQL Server Debugging to debug the sp. For more information, you could refer to the related link: [How can I step into a SQL Server stored proc from my C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784471/11507778).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, guys! Your suggestions have been invaluable. I appreciate all the help!